# Parcel delivery to LHR

Tags: transit, layovers, lhr, shipping

Itinerary: ARN-LHR-CMB

*Is it possible to have a parcel delivered to LHR? Into the transit zone?*

I know security reasons are an issue, but they could just send it through an x-ray. Otherwise, I could leave the airport during my 4h layover and pick it up outside, if there is a facility that can receive it.

Comment: Which terminal are you transiting through? Are you sure you have enough time to get through immigration and security, especially with all the trouble in UK airports these days? Do you have the right paperwork (citizenship or visa) to actually enter the UK? I’m pretty sure airside is not an option. There may be options landside but this seems awfully tight to me if you can’t use the e-gates.

Comment: The obvious question is why the parcel could not be delivered to CMB, your destination (outside the EU and UK) ?  What kind of goods are in the parcel also matters as it's not inconceivable that LHR customs are security would take issue with it if you were trying to board a flight to CMB.

Answer (score 5):

They could but they will not.

I was looking at an item available at the main Harrods store at Brompton road and I tried to arrange pickup at the Harrods in Heathrow. The main Harrods store redirected me to the Reserve & Collect Team at Heathrow which have claimed this is not possible and they said there's no service to do this.

Closest to Heathrow, I am not sure, but probably the DHL Service Point LHR1KI.

[image]

https://goo.gl/maps/2KW86F3vAS3zreiw5 (on the way back, Google is totally drunk suggesting a long roundabout walk, disregard, just walk on Bath Road, there is a sidewalk, you can even see it in Street View)

And as the comment suggest: do not even think doing this on a four hour layover. Maybe previous years you could risk it but even then it'd be risky but in 2022? The EU no longer applies a modicum of sanity to UK security procedures *and* you have staff shortages. I would avoid security at any UK airport like the plague. (Although, as we have just seen, even that saying is deprecated. Madness rules this world.)

Comment: *The EU no longer applies a modicum of sanity to UK security procedures*  The UK decided to leave the EU and it's the UK that created any security issues related to that.  The UK may like to blame the EU for all their problems, but they were warned of all these issues before the voted to leave.  Not the EU's fault.

Comment: Never did I imply that it would be the EU's fault. I merely stated the enforcement of _some_ sanity no longer applies. Of course the UK is to blame.

Comment: I also found that there is a Royal Mail Post Office in Terminal 3, and it should be possible to get stuff shipped there. 5h layover now, because SriLankan changed schedule. I will double check the situation before I take any risk.

Comment: I am well aware of the Post Office in the WHSmith both T3 and T5 but I didn't think they would hold your packages. What makes you think they would?