# Can I get a package delivered so I can pick it up during a layover at Newark airport?

Tags: airports, ewr, mail

I have a layover at Newark airport (EWR). It is a decent amount of time (4.5 hours) to not have to rush straight to the gate, but not enough to go into the city. However, there are some product I would like to buy, which I can likely not get at the airport but that can be easily bought online.

Is there a way to deliver these to a place where I can easily pick them up during my layover?

Comment: How will these packages be set?  Answers may vary depending on whether they're sent by the postal service or by a private courier like UPS or FedEx.  (For the first one you could use General Delivery;  not sure for the others.)

Comment: And what are your plans if you buy the product, and it isn't delivered in your time window? (assuming that it can be delivered to where you want)

Comment: Best option might be to find a company with a branch at the airport who allow you to order online and collect in store, although there's no guarantee such a company exists. There's [a similar question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/174818/parcel-delivery-to-lhr) about London Heathrow which was answered in the negative. A lot of mail order companies won't deliver to a parcel box/locker/etc outside their own network. Probably better delivering to somewhere else, e.g. a parcel collect point in your final destination.

Comment: In response to the comments: delivery be with whatever service is best - I am not bound to a specific delivery service. This is not a high-ticket item and if I miss the pickup and lose my money, that is no the end of the world. It is just so hard to get it in my country that it is worth trying to get it in the US.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the item can be bought on Amazon, and will fit into an Amazon locker, there are many such locations near Newark airport that should be easily reached within in your time frame.

From what I understand, once an item is delivered you have up to 3 days to pick it up.  But the challenge is to predict the delivery time so that those 3 days overlap with your layover at Newark, and I'm not sure what happens if you don't pick the package up.

See [Find an Amazon Hub Locker](https://www.amazon.com/gp/help/customer/display.html?nodeId=GVZLTK8D4EBS4QJA)

[image]

Comment: Fantastic! That seems to serve greatly for my purposes!

Comment: FYI if you don’t pickup from an Amazon locker, it gets returned to Amazon and you get refunded.

Comment: Thanks @DoxyLover, that makes it an even more practical solution!